# cannot run a node.js example

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a pre developed example in node.js environment. But i keep on getting the following error:
   **Cannot find module '/build/default/validation'**

Am I missing some module installation from **npm** here...? I have installed all the other modules like socket-io, websocket, websocket-server, websocket-clien, etc.

-Parag

Comment: We need to see your code or at least the "Example" you're following. It's very possible that it's out of date or like the other person said you may not have run `npm install` yet!

Comment: what's the example? did you try `npm install .` in the folder of that project? provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the package.json file for all required modules. Run `npm install` and `npm update` to automatically install all required modules and update them.

Usually, npm modules are in a folder *node_modules*, so */build/default/...* looks like some custom module that should be shipped with the example.